# Durandal Routing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, durandal-2.0

I want to send parameter with default route in durandal js.

```
 { route: '', title: 'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
```

like

```
{ route: 'test/:id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/test', nav: true },
```

But unfortunately I can't do it.
I want to set the url as
'http://domainname.com/123' where '123' is the paramater(id).
'http://domainname.com/#test/123' is working for me according to the second route.
Can anyone please help me.?

Comment: You can write a route like: `{ route: '(:id)', title: 'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true }` however it will only work urls like `http://domainname.com/#123` and not with `http://domainname.com/123`. In order to work with your example you need to fix this in your webserver/webapplication level and cannot be done only in durandal....

Comment: If the value is a default, why do you need to pass it? You can infer the value from the absence of a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is not possible - and it's by design.
You can refer to both [Durandal's own documentation on the router](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html) and also this [post in Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/durandaljs/F0TqaqYPnPw/CYC4YQvlTd8J) where Rob Eisenberg (creator of Durandal) has provided a show answer on the subject himself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actuallly you can handle this if u make your default or home page, an inner page . . . i've done this before and it works.

i know this is not the behavior or the expected approach, but since an argument (or param) belong to something, you should expect a route in order to send a param to it.